# how can i combine two form field values into a single mysql table column?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i looked around and can't find info on this, and the things i did find are close but no cigar.

lets' say i have these form fields:

```
<input type="text" name="field1" />
<input type="text" name="field2" />
<input type="text" name="field3" />
<select name="selectfield">
<option value="">select</option>
<option value="one">one</option>
<option value="two">two</option>
<option value="three">three</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="textfield" />
```

and a database table like so:

```
id, field1, field2, field3, field4
```

so what i want is for form fields 1 through 3 to go into table columns 1 through 3, then i want the values of the 4th and 5th form fields to go into the 4th table column.  something like this, but i doubt this is how it's done...

```
mysql_query("INSERT tableName SET field1='$field1', field2='$field2', field3='field3', field4='$selectfield + $textfield' ") or die(mysql_error());
```

**edit:** sorry meant fields 1 - 3 go into columns 2 through 4, and the last 2 fields go into 5th column.  forgot to count id column.

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. Moreover, please switch to [prepared statements](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: FYI: The syntax is [`INSERT INTO tableName`](http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-insert-statement.htm) and don't use `MySQL_` use `MySQLi_` at the very least. PDO is much better and safer.

Comment: you can concatenate the $selectfield and $textfield and store it in a variable say $newfield and then can use 'mysql_query("INSERT into tablename SET field1='$field1', field2='$field2', field3='field3', field4='$newfield' ") or die(mysql_error());'

Answer (score 1):

```
$field1 = $_POST['field1'];
$field2 = $_POST['field2'];
$field3 = $_POST['field3'];
$selectfield = $_POST['selectfield'];
$textfield = $_POST['textfield'];

$newtext = $selectfield . $textfield ; // concatenation

mysql_query("INSERT into tablename SET field1='$field1', field2='$field2', field3='field3', field4='$newtext' ") or die(mysql_error());
```

You can use something like this for youe ease. Thanks.

Comment: Fix this `$_Post` - $_POST is a superglobal. And your code will ultimately **"FAIL"**

Comment: i can't try anything until monday, but this looks like what i need.

Comment: @fred-ii - My code may fail, and so will your comments. Inheritance ;)

Comment: Another major problem with this example is that it's wide open for injection.

Comment: @DevUtkarsh oh, how so?

Comment: i use lines like this anyway...
$field_3 = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['field_3']));

Comment: @leoarce Well at least someone knows what he/she is doing. Good, yet do use `MySQLi` and/or PDO instead.

Comment: @leoarce - thats the best way to prevent sql injections.

Comment: lol on both counts.  i'm Leo, Arce is last name.  so yes a guy.

Comment: @leoarce Well, we've cleared "that" up, cheers and good luck.

Answer (score 0):

In database design it is not a good idea to keep the sum in table, it is better to keep in two fields,(also I think seems that you need a foreign key ) and before view the data to user concat them,

or

```
mysql_query("INSERT tableName SET field1='$field1', field2='$field2', field3='field3', field4='".$selectfield.$textfield."' ") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: The syntax is `INSERT INTO tableName` ;-)

Comment: http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-insert-statement.htm <= do read up on the subject.